# How to clear Data off of a VFD220F Display

Tags: vb.net

When I attempt to write to the display its working and shows me the text, but when I delete the text from textbox and press send data it does not change on display, leaving the previous text.  If I write another text and send it, it shows me both the old text and new text on the same line.

My question is: How I can delete old text from display and show the new text?
I am using the code below:

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Nport As String In SerialPort.GetPortNames
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(Nport)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            With SerialPort1
                .PortName = ComboBox1.Text
                .BaudRate = 9600
                .DataBits = 8
                .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
                .Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
            End With
            If Not (SerialPort1.IsOpen = True) Then
                SerialPort1.Open()
            End If
            SerialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer()
            SerialPort1.Write(TextBox1.Text)
            SerialPort1.Close()
            MsgBox("Data sent")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You used the above code then what happened ? right now this is just a code dump with no question just a request for us to write it for you.

Comment: Ok In any part I can put code dump?

Comment: It need to be cleaned up. Right now you are opening a serial port and attempting to write the value of a textbox to the display. What is currently missing is a question and a problem statement. What happens when you attempt to write to the display? Is it gibberish, blank or does it burst into flames. Since we are not there we need all of the information you can give us.

Comment: When I attempt to write to the display its working and show me the text. but when i delete the text from textbox  and press send data it no change on display and the text is still on display and after write another text and send its show me old text and new text in same line. My question: how i can delete old text from display and show the new text?

Comment: see this doc from the manufacture. Note the clear function. (&H0C) https://www.seetron.com/vfdx20/vfdx20prog.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the control codes that are provided by the display to clear it. According to the [manufacturers documentation](https://www.seetron.com/vfdx20/vfdx20prog.html) some of the available control codes are:

> **Home**  ---------------- 0x1  hex  1 Decimal
>   **Backspace**  --------- 0x8  hex  8 Decimal
>   **Tab**  ------------------- 0x9  hex  9 Decimal
>   **Line feed**  ----------- 0xA  hex 10 Decimal
>   **Clear Scrn**  --------- 0xC  hex 12 Decimal
>   **Carriage Return**  - 0xD hex  13 Decimal

Using the above you can do something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim displayHome As Byte() = New Byte(0) {&H1}
    Dim displayClear As Byte() = New Byte(0) {&HC}
    Dim displayNewLine As Byte() = New Byte(0) {&HD}
    Dim displayLineFd As Byte() = New Byte(0) {&HA}


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each Nport As String In SerialPort.GetPortNames
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(Nport)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            With SerialPort1
                .PortName = ComboBox1.Text
                .BaudRate = 9600
                .DataBits = 8
                .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
                .Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
            End With
            If Not (SerialPort1.IsOpen = True) Then
                SerialPort1.Open()
            End If
            SerialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer()
            'This is one way though the manufacturer doesn't
            'recommend it do to screen flashing.
            SerialPort1.Write(displayClear, 0, 1)
            SerialPort1.Write(TextBox1.Text)
            'Another way would be to go to the home position
            'and make sure you pad enough to cover all of the 
            'previous total.
            SerialPort1.Write(displayHome, 0, 1)
            SerialPort1.Write(TextBox1.Text.PadLeft(20))
            SerialPort1.Close()
            MsgBox("Data sent")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Hall now it's working ok, Just i changed this code line from: SerialPort1.Write(TextBox1.Text.PadLeft(20)) to SerialPort1.Write(TextBox1.Text.PadLeft(40)), Because (20)) it displays two lines and (40)) it displays one line